# How can I find the right inbound rule for my Github action to deploy on my AWS EC2 server?

Tags: github, amazon-ec2, deployment, tcp, github-actions

I just created the action on my project and configured everything over there, but unfortunately I'm getting a message like this into the 'deploy file' section> ssh: connect to host ec2-MYIP.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com port 22: Operation timed out

[image: Error due to EC2 security]

Good thing is that I know what's happening. I have to allow as an Inbound Rule the following:

Type: SSH / Protocol: TCP / Post range: 22 / Source: ::/0;

[image: EC2 inbound rules to make it work]

As you can see here, it works fine without limiting the source IP >
[image: When I don't specify any source for the TCP port 22]

But obviously I don't want to do that for security reasons, so I need to find out the source I need to put there.
I've tried a lot of Github IP addresses already, but all of them were unsuccessful.

Does anyone here know what's the right source for it to work in a protected way or how can I find it?

Action I am using > https://github.com/wlixcc/SFTP-Deploy-Action

Comment: Dare I ask, should the IP address not be your local machine or from wherever you are executing the command from?

Comment: Good question @GregoryNikitas, but I tried it already as well, and it didn't work. Do you have any other idea?

Answer (score 12):

An improved answer over riQQ's: Dynamically retrieve the Github Action runner's IP address during your workflow using the [public-ip action](https://github.com/haythem/public-ip) and
update your EC2 server's security group ingress rules before and after your SSH steps.

Your EC2 instance will never be exposed to public IP addresses on your SSH port.

**Note**: You will need to also [set AWS credentials](https://github.com/aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials) on your runner with permissions to update the associated EC2 security group.

Your workflow should look something like this:

```
  deploy:
    name: deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      AWS_INSTANCE_SG_ID: <your-ec2-security-group-id>
    steps:
      - name: configure aws credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
        with:
          aws-access-key-id: <your-ci-aws-access-key>
          aws-secret-access-key: <your-ci-aws-secret-key>
          aws-region: <your-ec2-aws-region>
      - name: get runner ip address
        id: ip
        uses: haythem/public-ip@v1.2
      - name: whitelist runner ip address
        run: |
          aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress \
            --group-id $AWS_INSTANCE_SG_ID \
            --protocol tcp \
            --port 22 \
            --cidr ${{ steps.ip.outputs.ipv4 }}/32
      - name: ssh into your ec2 and do whatever
        run: |
          ...do whatever you need to do...
      - name: revoke runner ip address
        run: |
          aws ec2 revoke-security-group-ingress \
            --group-id $AWS_INSTANCE_SG_ID \
            --protocol tcp \
            --port 22 \
            --cidr ${{ steps.ip.outputs.ipv4 }}/32
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Worked like a charm. No need to have a large IP address range open on your ACL. Thanks for this.

Comment: Hey, after creating the Identity Provider in AWS IAM, and the Trusted Policy following GitHub recommendations. Where do I get the aws-access-key-id and aws-secret-access-key ? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The IP addresses of GitHub hosted runners are documented here: https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/specifications-for-github-hosted-runners#ip-addresses

> Windows and Ubuntu runners are hosted in Azure and have the same IP address ranges as Azure Data centers.
> [...]
> Microsoft updates the Azure IP address ranges weekly in a JSON file that you can download from the [Azure IP Ranges and Service Tags - Public Cloud website](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519). You can use this range of IP addresses if you require an allow-list to prevent unauthorized access to your internal resources.